# Vim: Repeat previous motion?

Tags: vim

Let's say that I'm in visual mode, and I type "aw" to extend the visual area to include the next word.  I'd like to then include the next couple of words.  Is there a single key that I can press to repeat the previous motion (include text object motions)?

I'm aware that '.' repeats the previous change, and 'n' repeats the previous search, amongst other 'repeat' commands, but I'm unaware of any command to repeat the previous motion (whatever it was).

Comment: Builtin repeat motion commands `,` and `;` only work for motions `fFtT`.
No general command, you have to use a plugin.

Comment: There are a few things you can still do without plugins. For instance, see https://superuser.com/questions/429917/repeat-last-normal-mode-command-including-moves-in-vim  I've consolidated whatever I found in [my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76778797/)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are some plugins that provide this functionality:

- [repmo.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2174): repeat motions for which a count was given
- [repeatable-motions.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4914): Make most motions repeatable
- [repmo.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3665): give vim support of repeat motion operations (k,j, h,l, w,b, W,B, e,E, ge,gE)

Comment: I wanted to repeat `[{` style motions. `repeatable-motions.vim` works out of the box for that (repmo doesn't appear to).

Comment: It exists in emacs.  Get on it, Vim devs! 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275842/is-there-a-repeat-last-command-in-emacs

Answer (score 83):

Well there is a command to repeat every motion made with f,t,F or T
Remember that
**fx** takes to the next occurrence of the character x
**Fx** takes to the previous ocurrence of x
**tx** takes you to the character before the next occurrence of x
**Tx** takes you you to the character after the previous occurrence of x
to repeat those motions press

```
;
```

to repeat them backwards (in the oposite direction) press

```
,
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer.

Comment: Of note, when repeating `t` or `T`, `;` is different than just typing the command again.  For example, if you type `t(t(`, you won't get past the first `(` character.  But if you type `t(;`, you'll go to the second `(`.  See `:help cpo-;`.

Comment: There seems to be no built in way to repeat motions like `gE`, `10j`, ...

Comment: @NikhilCSB There are still some things you can do. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76778797/).

Answer (score 5):

There's still some hope if you're aiming to go sans plugins.

**Case 1**

For simply doing `j/k` jumps, nelstrom's answer<sup>[1]</sup> works well. For performing `100j` and `100k` respectively:

- `:+100` or `:-100`
- `@:` (repeats the last command).

**Case 2**

Using `norm`. From the manual:

> Execute Normal mode commands {commands}. This makes it possible to
> execute Normal mode commands typed on the command line.

- `norm 100j` followed by our trusty `@:`

The advantage here is we can apply this to do other motions too, say `norm 10l` for going right 10 steps.

**Case 3**

Macros are your friend. JK ABC's answer does say their usage "requires more spiritual power"<sup>[2]</sup> but once you learn the basics, you can wreak havoc on all repetitive tasks in your editor.

They shine when it comes to repeating motions too. Look up the basics of macros if you aren't familiar with them already.

- `q1` (start recording a macro in register 1)
- `100j` (your movement)
- `q` (stop the recording)
- `@1` (replay macro at register 1. If done once, you can then use the easier-on-the-hands `@@` to re-run the last used macro)

This has even more flexibility in the sense that you can store any custom motion in different registers (a-Z, 0-9 etc) and execute any one at a flick of your wrist.

**References**

<sup>[1][nelstrom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6221440/) from [How to jump down X amount of lines, over and over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220836/how-to-jump-down-x-amount-of-lines-over-and-over)</sup>

<sup>[2][JK ABC's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1155979/) from [Repeat last normal mode command, including moves, in Vim](https://superuser.com/q/429917/) (Super User)</sup>

Comment: `:+num` or `:-num` and `@:` is exactly what I was looking for - thank you, @joeljpa! ^5

Answer (score 4):

Instead of repeating the motion, there is a plugin for expanding regions via `+` and shrinking `_`: https://github.com/terryma/vim-expand-region

Answer (score 2):

NO PLUGINS use `;.`

Here's a detailed example:

```
int function1(){
   some code here;
   ...
   ...
   return 0;
}

int function2(){
   some code here;
   ...
   ...
   return 0;
}
```

Now let's say you want to rewrite the part inside `{}` for function1 and function2.

- Place your cursor somewhere inside the `{}`
- From Normal Mode (`ESC` or `ctrl+c`), press `di}` (for "delete" "inner" "{")
- Now you've deleted everything in the function
- Now bring your cursor inside the `{}` of function2
- Press `;.`

---

For visual mode, I think macros is your only option (maybe overkill for `aw`)

- To start recording a macro, press `q` + `q` (that last `q` can be any letter. It's where you macro will be saved)
- ... do the actions you want to repeat ...
- Press q again to stop recording

To replay these actions (even in visual mode):

- `@q` (or whatever letter you saved it to)

To replay the actions 99 times:

- `99@q` (or whatever letter you saved it to)

Comment: Feeling a bit shocked that I'm only now learning about the `di}` movement...

Comment: wouldn't it work if you just pressed `.` no `;`?

Comment: While this is interesting and I did learn something, I don't see how this answers the question. OP asked for ways to repeat a previous motion. This deletes text under a function and redoes that again? Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a small [vim-remotions](https://github.com/vds2212/vim-remotions) plugin that allows to repeat the last motion using the <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> keys (like for the `f` and `t` motions).

By default it repeats the following motions: `]m`, `]M`, `]]`, `][`, `}`, `g;`, `]b`, `]l`, `]q`, `]t`, `]g`.

It use the motion as they are defined in the buffer by the `filetype`.

The list of motions it repeats is configurable.

It can repeat the motion and their count or only the motion.

It can repeat the motion in the direction of the initial motion (like <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> are doing for `f` and `t`) or in the direction of the document if considered more intuitive.

Thanks to @romainl for his hints.