# How to repeat multi-line movement ( num + j,k) easily in vim?

Tags: vim

Some times I need to navigate through a new file, and I need constantly type `10j` or `20j`.

I'm wondering if there is a short-cut or some kind of config which allows me to press only 1 key to repeat the last movement.

I've searched online briefly, but no obvious solution yet.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: there's a vim-script for this: https://github.com/vim-scripts/repmo.vim

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553239/vim-repeat-previous-motion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<C-d>` and `<C-u>` to scroll down and up by half-screens.

Also, `<C-e>` and `<C-y>` (scroll down and up) can take a count so:

```
nnoremap <key>      10<C-e>
nnoremap <otherkey> 10<C-y>
```

There's also this very simple way to get an actionable outline of the current buffer:

```
:g/func/#
```

then do `:23` to jump to the corresponding line.

Answer (score 1):

you can save it to a register.

1. type `q` and then type a register, let's say `z`.
2. type `10j`
3. type `q` to exit motion.

then when you want to do `10j` next time, simple type `@z`.

Comment: type @ require `shift + 2`, besides, this is still 2 key stroke.

Comment: sorry. my fault. I searched this a little bit and find this. http://superuser.com/questions/429917/repeat-last-normal-mode-command-including-moves-in-vim

Comment: If you use macros, there is `@@` that repeats the last macro that was executed. It is faster than `@k` each time where `n` is a key. I find it quite useful!