# Nano-like scrolling in vim

Tags: vim

So my problem is that vim lags a little when I scroll, specially when I have multiple splits open.

I'd like to scroll in vim as in nano: when I scroll down/up it shouldn't load only a single line, it should load multiple lines.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to jump down X amount of lines, over and over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220836/how-to-jump-down-x-amount-of-lines-over-and-over)

Comment: I don't think this is a programming-related question. It belongs more to [Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'scrolljump'`, and set it to the minimum amount of lines to scroll at a time:

```
:set scrolljump=5
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you actually scrolling or are you only moving the cursor?

In Vim, scrolling vertically is done with `<C-e>` and `<C-y>` (line-by-line), `<C-d>` and `<C-u>` (half-screen-by-half-screen) or `<C-b>` and `<C-f>` (screen-by-screen), while moving the cursor vertically is done with `jk`.

You can adjust the `scroll` option to alter the behavior of `<C-d>` and `<C-u>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 'ttyfast' option? See:

`:help 'ttyfast'`
for help, and:

`:set ttyfast`
to enable it.

Also, what version are you using? And have you tried this with no customizations to see if something you've set is interfering?

Run it like this to omit any of your vimrc settings and plugins:

vim -u NONE

You can also use:

`:set lazyredraw` will buffer screen updates instead of updating all the time. I generally enable it when I'm doing a complex macro playback. Might help you here.

Comment: It does work with "vim -u NONE". I think the lag is because the syntax highlight. I'm using Vim 7.4

Comment: I've tried all of these before and none worked for me. Maybe it's because the mac terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can move faster between lines in the command mode:

```
<number of lines> k ... UP
<number of lines> j ... DOWN
```

Write it without brackets of course...